# Exported BigQuery table has different number of rows than the original BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I noticed that when using either the API or GUI to export a BigQuery table to Google Cloud Storage produces very different row counts.

Also, note that the BigQuery table is completely denormalized (flat table), and it's being exported compressed (gz), and partitioned (ie. part-*.gz).

Why would this happened?

Comment: More details needed. Job id? How different were the row counts? Was this a table that was being modified at the time. Compression (.gz) is optional for example https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.extract.

Comment: job_id -> midgar-djoanes:9afcd969-723f-4c45-bdbd-d56677d46a63, table definitely was not being modified, gz enabled